# ADO.Net Transaction when Command's transaction is not set

Tags: ado.net, transactions

I came across a sample on ADO.Net, where a transaction was being done without setting the command's transaction property as in code below.

Is this possible Or one needs to explicitly set the command's transaction property?

```
// Start a local transaction.
SqlTransaction sqlTran = connection.BeginTransaction();

// Enlist a command in the current transaction.
 SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
-----
-----
sqlTran.Commit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should throw a runtime exception. That is, if you have an active transaction on a `SqlConnection` and do not assign a reference to the corresponding `SqlTransaction` to the `SqlCommand.Transaction` property and attempt to execute the command, you should get an exception.

In short, set the `Transaction` property explicitly when executing a command on a connection with an active transaction.

Comment: Is there a property on connection object called 'Enlist' that might automatically include the command using a connection in a transaction, that might come into play here?

Comment: The `EnlistTransaction` method on `SqlConnection` is for something else; it's for enlisting the connection into a distributed transaction.